# beautifulsoup to seperate &nbsp and ; within a tag of html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My code

```
html = "<td>1.08&nbsp; 8.00&nbsp; 151.00</td>"
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml").renderContents()
```

The output:

```
<html><body><td>1.08  8.00  151.00</td></body></html>
```

Desired output:

```
1.08 ; 8.00 ; 151.00 ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
... html = "<td>1.08&nbsp; 8.00&nbsp; 151.00</td>"
... soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
>>> print(soup.find('td').text)
1.08  8.00  151.00
>>> nums = soup.find('td').text.split()
>>> nums
['1.08', '8.00', '151.00']
>>> ' ; '.join(nums)
'1.08 ; 8.00 ; 151.00'
```